# How do i re-assign useState from using array placement to their ids?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I built out an array of responses for a decision tree, and I'm using useState to have each question's answers take you to a different response using their placement in the array`jumpToQuestion`. This was not good, I need to delete some objects now and it's going to mess up the assignments. I just put in ids for all of them but now I need to reconfigure my `const [currentQuestion, setCurrentquestion] = useState(0)` to have it use the ids instead of array placement.

PS NOT ALL OF THE ARRAY IS HERE, THATS WHY SOME JUMPS GO PAST WHATS ON HERE. I DID THIS TO KEEP THE CODE SHORT.

```
const responses = [
    {
      id: 1,
      questionText: "Is the account data entry?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "No", isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 6 },
      ],
      notes: [
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      questionText: "Is this customer 1 or 2?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "No", isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 7 },
      ],
      notes: [
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      questionText: "Is the caller",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "Power of Attorney/Conservator", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 15 },
        { answerText: "Lawyer", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 13 },
        { answerText: "Emergency Responder", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 14 },
        { answerText: "Wanting to make a payment", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 14 },
        { answerText: "None", isCorrect: false },
      ],
      notes: [
      ],
    },
    

  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);

  const handleAnswerButton = (jumpToQuestion) => {
    const nextQuestion = jumpToQuestion || currentQuestion + 1;
    setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="appWrapper">
        <div className="headerContainer">
          <div className="alderlogo">
            <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" />
          </div>
          <div class="vl"></div>
          <h1 className="headerName">Verification Procedure</h1>
        </div>

        <button className="backBtn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i></button>

        <h2>{responses[currentQuestion].questionText}</h2>
        <div className="answerSection">
          {responses[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
            <button onClick={() => { handleAnswerButton(answerOption.jumpToQuestion) }}>{answerOption.answerText}</button>
            ))}
        </div>
        <div class="hl"></div>
        <div className="notesContainer">
          {responses[currentQuestion].notes.map((notePoints) => (
            <li>{notePoints.note}</li>
            ))}
          <h3>{responses[currentQuestion].addnotes}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor `responses` from an array of objects to an object, where every key / value pair is the id / response. I.e. the id is the key and the response object is the value. Leave your state hook as is (i.e. keeps the current question's id and defaults to the first question) and then you can keep using `response[currentQuestion]` to get the object you want.

Hope this helps and good luck!